# Can someone tell me how I would allow the User who visits localhost:5000/play/5/(color) to see the color they've selected to appear?

Tags: python, flask

Hi I am trying to figure out how to write some code in Python/ HTML that allows users who visit my URL to select a color that they would like to see in my boxes. For example: localhost:5000/play/5/green would display 5 beautiful green boxes. Calling localhost:5000/play/35/red would display 35 beautiful red boxes.

I already have the quantity of boxes figured out, but the color is tripping me up.

Comment: Could you share the code that you have created so far? This would be helpful to suggest a way for adding your color functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the color value from the route to the template:

```
import flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/play/<val>/<color>', methods=['GET'])
def generate_boxes(val, color):
  return flask.render_template('boxes.html', color=color, _iter = range(int(val)))
```

Then, in `boxes.html`:

```
<html>
 <style>
   .box{
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
    }
 </style>
 <body>
  {%for _ in _iter%}
    <div class='box' style='background-color:{{color}}'></div>
    <div class='spacer' style='height:10px;'></div>
  {%endfor%}
 </body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]